# How can we assume that reaching the speed of light slows down time?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, observers

How can we assume that gaining the speed of light slows down time?

Comment: Though the question is phrased in an unclear way I'm guessing it's asking about the physical reality of time dilation. In that case there are [several questions that address this issue](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=time+dilation+real).

Comment: It is probably also worth pointing out that we don't assume this, we deduce it from more basic assumptions ie. relativity and the universal speed of light.

Comment: We don't assume this, we *measure* it's effects. Every day.

Answer (score 1):

A particle moving at the speed of of light does not experience time, as it has no rest frame. Furthermore, a particle cannot continuously accelerate and eventually reach the speed of light, since massless particles can only move as fast as light. They either move at the speed of light or do not exist at all.